# Pulling JSON data only after user location is fetched

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

Having an issue where I'm calling method on viewDidLoad, but it will return no data. If I add the method to a button, and wait until the location is plotted, and zoomed it data is properly pulled. My initial concept is to have it once the user allows location, it will pull in the data rather then having to wait to click on a button to call the method.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    // Instantiating location object
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    // Setting some parameters for the location object
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    // THIS IS THE METHOD NOT WORKING UNLESS ADDED TO A BUTTON, AND WAITING 
    // FOR IT TO ZOOM, WHICH I ASSUME READ THE USERS PLOTTED LOCATION?
    [self queryGooglePlaces:@"food|restaurant"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationManager.location.coordinate, 10*METERS_PER_MILE, 10*METERS_PER_MILE);

    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    //Get the east and west points on the map so you can calculate the distance (zoom level) of the current map view.
    MKMapRect mRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
    MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));

    //Set your current distance instance variable.
    currentDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

    //Set your current center point on the map instance variable.
    currentCentre = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
}
-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Formulate the string as an URL object
    NSURL *googleRequestURL = url2;

    // Retrieve the results of the URL
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that the values for `currentCentre` is a zero point at viewDidLoad time hence the lack of food & restaurants.

You are going to have to wait for your user location to return a valid value by hooking

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)amapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation`

possibly

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)amapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

  currentCentre = userLocation.location.coordinate;

  if(thisIsNotTheFirstTime == NO) {

     [self queryGooglePlaces:@"food|restaurant"];
     thisIsNotTheFirstTime = YES;
  }

}
```

where `thisIsNotTheFirstTime` is an ivar. You'd have to explicitly init it YES if you want to eradicate the double-negative.

Comment: I want to eradicate the double-negative.

Comment: And, you should initialize it to a sane default value before using it in a conditional anyway.

Comment: Ok great, so I would just basically add Boolean thisIsNotTheFirstTime; in my header for the ivar, and by default the Boolean is NO ?

Comment: Yes,Boolean ivars are always reset to NO at init. Local vars must be explicitly set or they hold garbage.